# Is there a way for making Ubuntu stop muting headphone?

Tags: alsa, cron, headphones, mute

Ubuntu keeps muting my front headphone port(Onboard audio) every few minutes and though I am using a cron job to restore the status, is there any way I can put a stop to Ubuntu from doing it permanently?

Sometimes I get impatient and use this command on the terminal to bring back the volume instantly.

```
sudo alsactl --file ~/.config/asound.state restore
```

I am using Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate where the headphones are plugged into - for example is it the headphone socket in your monitor?

Comment: Done. It is the front headphone port on PC. (Onboard audio)